# 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class' while using Prophet

Tags: python, pystan, prophet

I am trying to use prophet.
I have installed all required packages:

```
pip install pandas numpy jupyterlab seaborn 
conda install pywin32 
conda install -c anaconda pystan=2.19.1.1=py38hac22706_0
conda install -c conda-forge prophet 
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow 
pip install darts 
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

Why `pystan=2.19.1.1=py38hac22706_0`? Because someone has this version and everything works well, so he sugested this version. The same Windows system, the same order of installing packages. But I got an error `'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'` while fitting the model :

```
model = Prophet()
model.fit(train)
prediction = model.predict(len(val))
```

I checked whether I really have `Pystan` and I really have it.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

uninstall fbprophet and pystan, then:

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
pip install prophet
```

and

```
from prophet import Prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after installing prophet while running a jupyter notebook. I simply restarted the kernel and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for `pystan==1.0.1` and `pystan==2.19.1.1`

error

> 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'

Can be caused by `pystan` version lower than `3.0.0`. Installing it on Windows machine can be problematic because of `httpstan` package.

As per [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/httpstan/) `httpstan` versions higher than 1.0.0 do not support Windows:

> Requirements
>
> ```
> Python version 3.7 or higher.
> macOS or Linux.
> C++ compiler: gcc ≥9.0 or clang ≥10.0.
> ```

Only solutions I found for now is to use `Docker` or `VM`. Windows also has [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)