# AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'

Tags: facebook-prophet, prophet

I am new to fb prophet to do time series analysis. I have this error. I have searched eveywhere  but couldnot find any solution. can you please help me :
AttributeError: 'StanModel' object has no attribute 'fit_class'

Comment: Previous aswer erased. This answer may satisfy you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483356/12603542

Comment: Still not working .. will you please suggest any other option?

Comment: This will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/68371071/9640885